# R install.package() paramaterize download.file() with options()

Tags: r, jenkins, devtools

I am running a Jenkins build and leveraging the [r-base docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/r-base).

I'm trying to install `devtools` I suspect that the Self-Signed certificates are my problem.

When I try to install the package.

```
install.packages("devtools", 
                 method = options("extra", " --insecure --user"))
```

I get the following error

```
 'arg' must be NULL or a character vector
```

How can setup package.install to ignore the certificates?  From what I've read I need to parameterize the `download.file()` with `options()` for the `method` parameter in `install.packages()` but I cannot figure out how.

**NOTE**:  I am not an R programmer, if this is something basic, I am happy to learn if there is an R tutorial on stuff like this somewhere.

What am I doing wrong with `method = options(...)` and how can I pass `-k` or `--insecure` to *libcurl*?

Comment: Try `install.packages("devtools", method = "libcurl", extra = " --insecure --user")`. `extra` is an argument, not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To `download.file` with `method = "libcurl"` and some extra options, pass those values in the respective arguments to the download file function.

```
install.packages("devtools", method = "libcurl", extra = " --insecure --user")
```

These options can be set with `options()`. The example below sets the method an other, extra, download file options. The previous settings are saved in `old_opt`.

```
libcurl_opts <- list(
  download.file.method = "libcurl",
  download.file.extra = " --insecure --user"
)

old_opt <- options(libcurl_opts)
```

Check to see it worked.

```
getOption("download.file.method")
#[1] "libcurl"
```

Now reset when done.

```
options(old_opt)
getOption("download.file.method")
#NULL
```